# React typescript counter doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I wrote my first component in react with typescript: a simple counter.

The tree is : Index -> App (react/js) -> counter (react/js).

Cliking the buttons the state.count is incremented/decremented. I see with the console.log, but the  tag with {state.count} isn't updated on click?

Why? Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your help.

I tried to add key property to div tag.

Counter.tsx

```
import React from "react";

interface IState {
  count: number;
}



export default function Counter(): JSX.Element {

const state: IState = { count: 0 };

const increment = (): any => {
  console.log(state);
     state.count= state.count + 1

};

const decrement = (): any => {
  console.log(state);

  state.count = state.count - 1;
};
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Counter</h2>
      <div>
        <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
        <div key={state.count}>{state.count}</div>
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Counter from "./counter";

export default function App():JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter />
      </div>
    );
}
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from './components/App'

const root = document.getElementById('app-root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

I expect that by clicking the buttons the number changes.

Comment: You update state in React by doing `setState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code solve the problem:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

interface IState {
  count: number;
}



export default function Counter(): JSX.Element {
 const [count, setCounter] = useState(0);
const state: IState = { count: 0 };

const increment = (): any => {
  console.log(state);
     setCounter(count+1);


};

const decrement = (): any => {
  console.log(state);
  setCounter(count -1);

};
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Counter</h2>
      <div>
        <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
        <div key={count}>{count}</div>
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are mutating the state!! Try this:

```
this.setState({count : this.state.count + 1})
```

Comment: on a note you can't mutate state with `state.variable = ...`

Comment: doen't work. setState brokes the js. Maybe I wrote a stateless component and I need to change the state outside it?

Comment: You need to turn it into a class component. Or use `useState`, the gist is to never mutate the state

Comment: Solved: I add UseState hook to my component and so it works. I understood that assign variable isn't change state is just assign a variable... One have to tell react that variable is the state.

Comment: Great! Consider accept the answer to close the question. Good luck!